# Killing vectors in an static space-time

Tags: general-relativity, vector-fields

How can I show that a given space-time is static, i.e. exists a time-like Killing vector $\xi = \partial_0$ that $\partial_0 g_{\mu \nu} = 0$ (Killing eq.) and $g_{0i}=0$, if and only if the relation
$$\xi_{[\alpha}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu]} = 0$$
holds?

I have already proved that if $\partial_0 g_{\mu \nu}=0$ and $g_{i0}=0$, then $\xi_{[\alpha}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu]} = 0$. I have no idea how to prove the inverse.

Comment: Nitpick:  Killing's equation is usually written as $\nabla_{(\mu} \xi_{\nu)} = 0$, without any reference to a particular coordinate $x^0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But for this special case the equation $\nabla _{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}=0$ takes the form $\partial_0 g_{\mu \nu} = 0$.

Comment: You need to use Frobenius' theorem. The condition on the Killing field implies that the integral line of the field are hypersurface orthogonal.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework-and-exercises tag.